# Difficulty creating a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL developer. This is what I want the procedure to do:

- insert a new customer using parameters values.
- set the SALE_HR value to zero.
- set the status value to 'OK'

This is what I have so far - it's not much as I've only started learning and I'm already super confused :(

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_CUST
IS
cid number(4);
cname varchar2(20);
BEGIN
```

I'm super new to SQL developer so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: oracle <> sql server. removed the sql server tag based on syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`cid`, and `cname` can be passed as procedure arguments.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_CUST(
    cid   IN NUMBER,
    cname IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO customer
    (cust_id,cust_name
    ) VALUES
    ( cid,cname
    );
END;
/
```

Call the procedure as

```
BEGIN
 ADD_CUST(20,'J Doe');
 COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: To save the transaction into the database.I suggest you to please go through the following link. You need to understand these basic  concepts better before starting to code . https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm